# laravel method in href link?

Tags: php, laravel, drop-down-menu

I want to create a dropdown with two links. A 'Delete' and a 'Edit' link.

For the delete function I created a form.

```
                        {!! Former::horizontal_open()->method('DELETE')->action(action("Test\\TestController@destroythread", $comment->id)) !!}
                        {!! Former::danger_submit('Delete') !!}
                        {!! Former::close() !!}
```

The form works, that means my comment get's deleted, if I'm pressing the button.

No I decided to remove the delete button and do a dropdown with a delete link. So I need to get the logic of this form in my dropdown menu.

But I haven't got this in the dropdown.. The optical 'Delete' button is this part of the dropdown:

```
<li><a href="#">
Delete
</a></li>
```

But I can't just put my controller function in that "href-link", cause without the 'DELETE'-Method, it won't work. I hope you all understand what I'm trying to say... my english isn't the best anyway.

Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks for any help!

I tried it like this before but this haven't worked either:

```
<li>
    <a>
        {!! Former::horizontal_open()->method('DELETE')->action(action("Test\\TestController@destroythread", $comment->id)) !!}
        Delete
        {!! Former::close() !!}
    </a>
</li>
```

my try linking directly to the route:

```
<li><a href="{{ route('destroy', $comment->id) }}">Delete</a></li>
```

and my Route looks like this:

```
Route::delete('/show/{id}', 'Test\\TestController@destroythread')->name('destroythread');
```

but this haven't worked for me..

all /show/ routes:

```
Route::get('/show/{id}', 'Test\\TestController@show');
Route::put('/show/{id}/edit', ['as' => 'editing', 'uses' => 'Test\\TestController@update']);
Route::get('/show/{id}/edit', 'Test\\TestController@edit')->name('edit');
Route::delete('/show/{id}', 'Test\\TestController@destroy')->name('destroy');


Route::delete('/show/{id}', 'Test\\TestController@destroythread')->name('destroythread');   // this is the route we are talking about
```

Comment: Why don't you link it to the route that uses `TestController@destroythread` ?

Comment: @JilsonThomas please have a look over my update :)

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5 right now

Comment: In your routes, define this: `Route::delete('/show/{id}', ['as'=>'destroy', 'uses'=>'Test\\TestController@destroy']);`   and in the href, use: `<li><a href="{{ route('destroy', $comment->id) }}">Delete</a></li>`

Comment: well my dropdown looks good right now but I just getting directed to my error page

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: If you are using a `delete` method, your delete request has to be passed through ajax if it's not a form button.

Comment: so i can't put this in a dropdown if I don't use ajax?

Comment: Yes, that's right. or you should use it in a form button with the form method as `delete`.

Comment: could you give me the code for that? cause I'm a little bit confused how this will look like o.o

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses method spoofing to do 'DELETE', 'PUT', 'PATCH' form requests. Like @Jilson Thomas mentioned, you can just create a link directly to the route. I suspect you're using resourceful routes, thats why you're trying to post a DELETE request?

Have a look at this section in the routing docs, this may help you out: https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers

Based on your routes posted, I believe the following two routes are matching before it gets to your desired route.

```
Route::put('/show/{id}/edit', ['as' => 'editing', 'uses' => 'Test\\TestController@update']);
Route::delete('/show/{id}', 'Test\\TestController@destroy')->name('destroy');
```

Try moving your desired route above these and see what happens.

**Edit**

```
<li><a href="{{ route('destroy', $comment->id) }}">Delete</a></li>
```

That will produce a GET request, therefore it will not match Route::delete(...). The previous method was posting a form to the route. Also, wrapping an entire form in an anchor tag is invalid markup.

Comment: I will update my question, please have a look over it in about a minute :)

Comment: Do you have any routes defined before the Route::delete(...) which would post to '/show/{id}'? I'm just wondering if you have a conflict in your routes.php

Comment: yes I have, I will update my question with all the /show routes I have :)

Comment: Can you inspect the network request via the chrome web inspector or fiddler? Does it show an actual POST (DELETE) request being sent or is it a GET request?

Comment: it's a delete request... And before the dropdown, I had a delete button, and there it was working perfectly. So I think it need's to be delete request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106373/discussion-between-btl-and-itzme488).

Answer (score 0):

So, as per the discussion in the comments, you'll have to use ajax request to do a `delete` request from an anchor tag.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/show/'+$('#testId').attr('value'),
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(data){ if(data.success) alert('Deleted'); },
    error: function() {} 
});
```

and in your route:

```
Route::delete('/show/{id}', ['as'=>'destroy', 'uses'=>'Test\\TestController@destroy']);
```

**HTML**

```
<li><a href="#" id="testId" value="{{$comment->id}}">Delete</a></li>
```

Comment: where do I put this ajax code? 

`<li><a href="{{ route('destroythread', $comment->id) }}">Delete</a></li>`  thats how my droptdown delete menu looks right now

Comment: I'm sorry, I've got some internet problems yesterday.. I will try this out now

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way, try '[Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html)' Html Helper.

**HTML**

```
{!! Form::open('delete', 
    'method' => 'delete,
    'route'  => ['show.destroy', $comment->id]
) !!}

     {!! Form::submit('Submit') !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::delete('show/{show}', [
  'uses' => 'TestController@destroy',
  'as' => 'show.destroy'
]);
```

Comment: well but this is a submit button. I know the way to do normal button, but I wan't a dropdown with a delete section in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

The form with method dont show and you can call a route / url with method POST/PUT/DELETE ...

```
<a href="{{ route('logout') }}" class="dropdown-item" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">Logout</a>
                  
<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('item/delete',) }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    @csrf
</form>
```